# How to connect to a hosted database?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have my databse hosted on a site.
How can I modify this:

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "amit");
```

in order to connect to my database hoted on the www.abc.com (example) site?

Answer (score 0):

Change "localhost" to the IP of the server where the database is hosted (and the credentials if they changed - I sure do hope you have a password in production!).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the database from another computer or server, maybe you have to modify the security properties of the database user. 
Sometimes only user from localhost can connect to the database.

To connect to the database you only have to change "localhost" to the server ip.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel server, from databse section check your databse name, username and password. Then change the value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**MYSQL CONNECTION**

```
<?php $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password'); if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } echo 'Connected successfully'; mysql_close($link); ?>
```

**MYSQL CONNECTION USING PORT**

```
<?php // we connect to example.com and port 3307 $link = mysql_connect('example.com:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password'); if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } echo 'Connected successfully'; mysql_close($link);

// we connect to localhost at port 3307 $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3307', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password'); if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } echo 'Connected successfully'; mysql_close($link); ?>
```

**MYSQLI CONNECTION**

```
<?php $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) { echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL; echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL; echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL; exit; }

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL; echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link); ?>
```

**PDO CONNECTION**

```
<?php try { $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass); foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) { print_r($row); } $dbh = null; } catch (PDOException $e) { print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>"; die(); } ?>
```